# Validar lista de archivos con ListBox

Tags: vb.net, archivo, eventos

[image: Aqui me aparece este warning que aun no he podido como resolverlo, de antemano agradezco sus consejos y orientacion.]Necesito que me ayuden con esta parte de mi código en VB , en el ListBox me tiene que aparecer una dirección IP para verificar ciertos datos que tengo que mostrar en pantalla al momento de que corro el programa siempre me sale una Advertencia de

> ArgumentException occured Empty path name is not legal

Llevo días buscando ese error ya debegue y cuando inspecciona la información me aparece una leyenda que  dice:

> Argument not specific for parameter 'sender' of 'Privite Sub
>   Listbox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)Handles ListBox1_Click

Anexo parte de mi código para que puedan verificar en que parte del código estoy mal.

```
 Private Sub ListBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.Click
    validar()
End Sub
 Public Sub validar()
    logfile = ListBox1.Text
    Dim file As New System.IO.StreamReader(logfile)
    Dim oneLine As String
    oneLine = file.ReadLine()
    RichTextBox2.Enabled = False
    While (oneLine <> "************ Report ***********")

        oneLine = file.ReadLine()
        If oneLine = "Final Status:         Passed" Then
            txtModelo.Clear()
            txtPO.Clear()
            txtDelivery.Clear()
            RichTextBox1.Clear()
            RichTextBox2.Clear()
            txtConsola.Clear()
            MessageBox.Show("El archivo seleccionado no contiene falla", "Part Replacement")
            Exit While
        ElseIf oneLine = "Final Status:         Aborted" Then
            RichTextBox2.Enabled = True
            MessageBox.Show("Este archivo contiene un abort, ingresa los comentarios de la falla", "Part Replacement")
        ElseIf oneLine = "************ Report ***********" Then
            logfile = ListBox1.Text
            leerdir()
            leerdel()
            leerfalla()
            leerpo()
            leermod()
            leerconsol()
            'materialType()
            SerealizadoFile()
            ImportarArchivo()
            MarketingPN()
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

Código del evento `Form1_Load`:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim thisDate As Date
    thisDate = Today
    txtFecha.Text = thisDate
    txtFechaCorta.Text = Format(thisDate, "yyyyMMdd")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(File)

    Dim currentTime As Date
    currentTime = TimeOfDay
    txtHora.Text = currentTime
    txtHoraDecimal.Text = Format(TimeOfDay, "hhmmss")

    If txtHoraDecimal.Text < 20000 Then
        txtTurno.Text = "1er"
    Else
        txtTurno.Text = "2do"
    End If
End Sub
```

Me dejaron un comentario que fue borrado:

> [**Jose Pilay:**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/47031/jose-pilay) ¿De dónde traes el `File` en esta línea `ListBox1.Items.Add(File)`?

Comment: Viene desde un server que utilizo para jalar el archivo y lo muestre dentro del ListBox1.

Comment: el codigo que muestras esta ubicado dentro del form? si vas al diseñador del form, selecionas el listbox y validas los eventos asociados al control puedes observar que el click es correcto

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Cheque el código como lo menciono y si el código esta dentro del form y al igual el click es correcto , lo que observe dentro de las propiedades del ListBox es que no tengo el evento de Load y al parecer eso esta causando que mi código no funcione correctamente. Me podría asesorar en que debo de hacer para que este evento de Load aparezca y cargue los datos que necesito?

Comment: Pero como te dijeron en el comentario borrado, de donde traes FILE? el listbox tiene items en el?? obviamente, esta vacio a primera vista

Comment: El File viene desde un server en el cual tengo acceso y en el programa tiene que mostrar la información que requiero al momento de que yo quiero mostrar los datos es donde falla y me dice que hay un error tengo esta dirección que es la que se encarga de jalar los datos y mostrarlos "\\10.49.127.12\Logs\CTO\JGD\Console\" , en este caso @gbianchi que me recomendarias hacer para que el archivo no lo muestre vacio?

Comment: en esta linea, ListBox1.Items.Add(File), File de donde viene?? esa variable que tiene?? el listbox tiene items o esta vacio??? el error es que el listbox esta vacio, entonces por favor centrate en ese problema primero..

Answer (score 0):

Buenas Elizabeth,

El error que aparece es un error emitido por System.IO.StreamReader y viene a decir que el nombre del archivo que le estas pasando esta vacío.

Deberías comprobar si el logfile tiene datos o no antes de pasarlo como parámetro para el StreamReader:

```
If logfile <> String.Empty Then
    Dim file As New System.IO.StreamReader(logfile)
    //Código que sigue con el File
End If
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportacion y en efecto esto ya lo solucione en esa misma forma , ahora lo que tengo es otro error en donde me dice que el path network no fue encontrado es lo siguiente:       System.IO.File.Copy(Ubicacion, Destino, True)   aqui me aparece una excepcion IO Exception was unhandled , the network path was not found   me podrias decir que puedo hacer en este caso?

Comment: Comprueba que no tienes el archivo que intentas copiar abierto a la hora de hacer el Copy haciendo un file.Close, si no es eso, intenta copiar el código donde tienes el File.Copy(Ubicacion, Destino, True) para poder ver el codigo.